# jQuery UI, Wait for dialog response

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm building a simple web-based text editor and am trying to implement something like a "Save changes?" dialog when the user tries to open a file and the current file has unsaved changes.

The code is something like this:

```
function openFile() {
    if (hasChanges === true) {
       $("#save-changes-dialog).dialog("open");
    }

    // file opening stuff goes here
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, since what happens is the dialog gets opened, and then the file opening code just runs right after opening the dialog rather than waiting for the results of that dialog.

What's the best approach to solve this problem? I have tried dynamically changing what the buttons do in the "Save Changes" dialog so that the file opening code is called by the dialog buttons themselves, but it seemed like a bit of a mess and I was also running into timing issues because of some AJAX calls.

This seems like something that would come up fairly often, but I can't seem to find a clear cut answer on how to approach the problem. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File opening stuff does not go "here". It goes into the dialog's button handler.

When you defined the dialog:

```
$("#save-changes-dialog").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Save: function() {
                // file opening stuff goes HERE instead!
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: So is the best approach to dynamically change what the button's do in the dialog depending on where it's being called from? They will do different things whether I'm opening a file, creating a new file, or navigating away from the page, for example. Or should there be a separate dialog for each situation? The other problem is that if the file with changes is an unsaved file, it has to call the "Save as" dialog, and then dynamically change that dialog's button handlers as well. It just seems like a messy, slippery slope...

Comment: I'd have separate dialogs, so that I can have different titles, and different text on buttons, and other specific things; it is much nicer (from UX point of view) to ask "Save/Cancel?" and "Load/Cancel?" than generic "OK/Cancel", and if you do all that by shapechanging one dialog, it's too much work. However, it is absolutely impossible to have a blocking dialog in JS (what you're proposing) aside from the basic ugly `prompt()` and `alert()`. You have to go asynch, and use callbacks. JS waits for no man.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function checkForChanges() {
    if (hasChanges === true) {
       $("#save-changes-dialog").dialog("open");
       return false;
    }
    openFile();
}

function openFile(){
    // file opening stuff goes here
}
```

Anywhere that previously called openFile should now call checkForChanges, and then in your dialog, you can call openFile() on any event you wish